# remove the rows in a matrix whose elements are the same in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Given a 2-column matrix, for instance. The input is:

```
[ 1,2;
  3,4;
  5,5]
```

The expected output is:

```
[1,2;
 3,4;]
```

Does anyone know how do accomplish this? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use logical indexing:

```
A = [1 2;3 4;5 5];
match = A(:,1) == A(:,2); // 1 where row has the same elements in both columns
A(match,:) = []; // make the match columns empty
```

You would need to make this more generic for another case, but for two columns and your example this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Your question suggests your matrix may have an **arbitrary number of columns**. In that case you may want to delete a row if it has (*a*) **any two** elements equal, or (*b*) **all** elements equal.

One possible approach is:

1. Apply [`sort`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) along each row;
2. Use [`diff`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to compute differences between consecutive elements;
3. Generate a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) with [`all`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) to (*a*) keep rows for which all such differences are non-zero, or with [`any`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) to (*b*) keep rows for which any such difference is non-zero:

So:

```
X = [1 2 3;
     3 4 3;
     5 5 5];
Y = X(all(diff(sort(X,2),[],2),2),:);
Z = X(any(diff(sort(X,2),[],2),2),:);
```

gives

```
Y =
     1     2     3
Z =
     1     2     3
     3     4     3
```